# Suggested elasticsearch configuration for a 3 node cluster for home use

Tags: elasticsearch

I have set up a simple elastic search cluster at home for testing and playing around. However, one aspect I am struggling with is figuring out a best practice configuration for my setup.

I currently have three nodes. A powerful VM instance and two raspberry pi's.

Up until recently the two raspberry pi nodes were set to both `node.master = false` and `node.data = false`. However, I would prefer to have more redundancy and make more use of my three nodes so I now have all three nodes set to `node.master` and I've set the `minimum_master_nodes` to 2.

So my question is whether this is a sensible setup for a test cluster? It wont be storing massive amounts of data or serving high amounts of search requests.

But I would like to achieve data redundancy by storing the data on at least two nodes. Is this as simple as just setting one of the raspberry pi's as `node.data: true`?

Thanks for any insight.

Comment: If a node needs to store data, then yes, you just need `node.data: true`. Since this is test, you can experiment whatever you want :-).

Comment: While it's for testing purposes I still want a semi-reliable configuration. Is it acceptable to have three master nodes where two of them stores data?

Comment: The rule of thumb is like this: have a dedicated master eligible node only if the load on that data node is so large that it can make the master drop off the cluster and trigger a new master election. So, you can have all your three nodes as storing data and, also, be master-eligible.